# Binding source doesn't change when setting the binding from code behind file

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app

So I have this program where I mainly do all my bindings by using `x:Bind` but I have a control page where I need to generate a lot of `Slider` to be able to manipulate the data I stored in an `ObservableCollection<T>`

I really need to generate those sliders from my code because I need around 100 of them and it would really mess up my xmal file to create them by hand...

This is how I create the bindings in my code. They also work when I load them the first time. But they don't change the source data when I move the slider around.

```
private void CreateGrid()
{
    for (var parameterNumberIndex = 1; parameterNumberIndex < 97; parameterNumberIndex++)
    {
        var paraName = new TextBlock()
        {
            Name = $"Parameter{parameterNumberIndex}",
            FontSize = 25,
            VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
            Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 10)
        };

        var slider = new Slider()
        {
            Name = $"ValueSlider{parameterNumberIndex}",
            Width = 200,
            VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
            HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center
        };

        var value = new TextBox()
        {
            Name = $"ValueBox{parameterNumberIndex}",
            Margin = new Thickness(10, 5, 0, 0),
            FontSize = 20,
            VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top
        };

        var row = new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(50, GridUnitType.Pixel) };

        SettingsGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(row);

        var nameBinding = new Binding
        {
            Source = ViewModel.BlockCollection.NamesBlock.Names[parameterNumberIndex].NameString,
            Mode = BindingMode.OneWay
        };

        var valueBinding = new Binding()
        {
            Source = ViewModel.BlockCollection.ParameterBlock.Parameters[parameterNumberIndex].ParameterValue,
            Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay
        };

        var minBinding = new Binding()
        {
            Source = ViewModel.BlockCollection.MinMaxBlock.AllValues[parameterNumberIndex].MinValue,
            Mode = BindingMode.OneWay
        };

        var maxBinding = new Binding()
        {
            Source = ViewModel.BlockCollection.MinMaxBlock.AllValues[parameterNumberIndex].MaxValue,
            Mode = BindingMode.OneWay
        };

        var textBinding = new Binding()
        {
            Path = new PropertyPath("Value"),
            Source = slider,
            Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay
        };

        BindingOperations.SetBinding(paraName, TextBlock.TextProperty, nameBinding);
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(slider, Slider.MinimumProperty, minBinding);
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(slider, Slider.MaximumProperty, maxBinding);
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(slider, Slider.ValueProperty, valueBinding);
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(value, TextBox.TextProperty, textBinding);

        SettingsGrid.Children.Add(paraName);
        SettingsGrid.Children.Add(slider);
        SettingsGrid.Children.Add(value);

        Grid.SetColumn(paraName, 0);
        Grid.SetColumn(slider, 1);
        Grid.SetColumn(value, 2);

        Grid.SetRow(paraName, parameterNumberIndex - 1);
        Grid.SetRow(slider, parameterNumberIndex - 1);
        Grid.SetRow(value, parameterNumberIndex - 1);
    }
}
```

The `Source = ...` are always `ObservableCollection<T>` depending on which type I need them in.

The slider source is a collection of `uint`.

The `BindableBase` is my implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

```
public class ParameterBlock : BindableBase
{
    public ParameterBlock()
    {
        this.Parameters = new ObservableRangeCollection<ParameterBlockValue>();
    }

    public ObservableRangeCollection<ParameterBlockValue> Parameters
    {
        get => _parameters;
        set
        {
            _parameters = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }        

    private ObservableRangeCollection<ParameterBlockValue> _parameters;
}

public class ParameterBlockValue : BindableBase
{
    private uint _parameterValue;

    public uint ParameterValue
    {
        get => _parameterValue;
        set
        {
            _parameterValue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ParameterBlockValue(uint parameter)
    {
        this.ParameterValue = parameter;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{this.ParameterValue} {Environment.NewLine}";
    }
}
```

This is nearly the last step I need to fix before I'm more or less done with this project and I don't want to get stuck here :/

I don't know if the wpf tag is wrong. But everytime I look for xaml references I stumble over the wpf stuff and it's somewhat usable. So if it's wrong just tell me and I remove it.

To explain a bit more... In the finished product it will depend on what data I recieve to decide if there will be a slider or a textbox.

Just a small example picture from another question I had yesterday:

[image]

Comment: "I need around 100 of them" sounds like they should be in an ItemsControl.

Comment: It will not just be sliders. It is/was just easier to test it like that first. Depending on the incoming data I could also need a TextBox or just a ToggleSwitch. I'm not really familiar with the ItemsControl but would it be usable in that case or just when I only have one specific type of element?

Comment: If you do not set an ItemsControl's ItemTemplate to a fixed DataTemplate (as shown in the answer), it is possible to show different DataTemplates for different item types. The source item collection might be declared as `ObservableCollection<object>`. Then just declare DataTemplates with a DataType property as resources. Start reading here: [Data Templateing Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you are adding the controls in a `Grid`, generating the rows manually. While this could certainly work, it would be much better to use a list control and create the items within:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{x:Bind Data}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- your Sliders, etc. -->
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
<ItemsControl>
```

If the data might vary between multiple layouts, you may implement a `DataTemplateSelector` class, override the `SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)` (this method specifically, there is another one with the same name but different number of parameters which is not called) and decide on the right template for each item. You can create multiple `DataTemplates` as resources with `x:Key` and then reference them from your `DataTemplateSelector`. See this [blog post](https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2013/02/18/dynamically-choose-datatemplate-in-winrt/) for an example and [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.datatemplateselector) for more details.

Comment: Thats definitely better as my approach :D I had some problems to get the binding working and I still have to implement the `DataTemplateSelector`but so far I'm really impressed on how much better it is :D